# Safari in OS X – weird bug with border-radius

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm experiencing some really strange problems with border radius in Safari for Mac OS X. Take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sXxtU/1/

**Safari Mac OS X:**
[image]
(Top left corner, and the white vertical line)

**Chrome Mac OS X:**
[image]
(Perfectly fine)

**Safari iOS 6.0**
[image]
(Also perfectly fine).

Now, in this example I am using `border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;`, i.e. only applying it on the top corners. However, if I chose to round all the corners – I get this (in Safari for OS X):

[image]

Is this a known bug? Is there some way to remedy this? I'm guessing that it is due to some clipping issues, but no matter how I try to apply different fixes – I can't get it to look quite right.

**Edit**
I should point out that this is in Safari 6.0.2. haven't got the chance to test other versions just yet.

**Edit 2**
Tried adding `border: 1px solid transparent;` and it looks much better. However, if I go with a border color (like #fff) I still get some clipping problems (now in the top right corner...?). Still very interested in learning what's going on here.

**Edit 3**
User Sparky pointed out that my HTML is invalid (having a div-element inside a ul-element) – however, I have confirmed that this have nothing to do with the issues I am having.

**Edit 4**
Been testing Safari 6.0.2 some older versions of OS X, and this issue only seems to occur in 10.8.2. Very strange.

Comment: What version of Safari do you use?

Comment: Weird border with Safari 6.0.2 with 10.8.2 ;) But if I add { float: left; } to .pill it's much better. If the width of the element is smaller than 220px it's ok ;)

Comment: Good on Safari 6.0.2 with 10.8.2

Comment: Okay, if I add `border: 1px solid transparent;` it seems to work much better – still some clipping issues though (in the right top corner it seems).

Comment: u can try border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; or try putting this:   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;

Comment: Looks good on Safari 6.0.2 on 10.7.5

Comment: @MishuSarker Nope – that yields the same results.

Comment: I cannot believe nobody noticed the invalid HTML.

Comment: @Sparky Yes, sorry but that misstake. However, it didn't have anything to do with this particular error/bug.

Comment: Just upgraded to 10.8.2 from 10.7.5 and while my comment above holds for Lion, in Mountain Lion border radius is messed up in Safari, I also get flickering screen in some edge cases of popup elements. Safari bug, let's wait for 6.0.3 and hope they fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are inserting a div clear inside of the unordered list. Your list items should be set as display: inline-block and your ul could have a clearfix on it to maintain it's proper height even though your list items are floating left.

I tested this in 6.0 and then in 6.0.2

Here's a fork of your jsfiddle with a few tweaks.

http://jsfiddle.net/rossedman425/VTySS/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="pill">
    <ul class="cf">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    padding: 20px;
}
.pill {
    background-color: #00a38f;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
ul {
    padding: 13px;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: After seeing all the comments above, I wonder if this has to do with 10.8.2. I am on 10.7.5 and had no problems with this.

Comment: I agree that it is probably something to do with the clear fix. You should be using that on block elements. display: block; that ul. I would suggest an overflow: hidden; instead on the clear-fix in this case. That will force it to extend. I would also think about position: relative; on these. Honestly, I use *{position: relative;} ::: on another note: .group or .clear would be a much more pleasing and immediately understood name for your clear-fix.

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact true and has nothing to do with the the way the code is written, it is a browser bug.

If you zoom in on a page with this bug, you will see that the rendering will display correctly for some zoom levels.

Still found no away to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem in my version of Safari.

However, I noticed that you have invalid HTML.  [As per the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html#h-10.2), and [the online HTML validator tool](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://jsfiddle.net/sXxtU/1/show/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), `<ul>` elements must only contain `<li>` elements as *immediate* descendants.

Your HTML code is invalid:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <div class="clear"></div> <!-- this line is invalid HTML -->
</ul>
```

Remove `<div class="clear"></div>` from the `<ul>` and see if that clears it up...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can use `overflow:` on the `<ul>` to force it to expand to contain its children and that totally eliminates the need for a clearing `div`.

```
ul {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sXxtU/7/

Comment: Thanks for the imput regarding the overflow. However, that still doesn't fix the clipping issues in 10.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that version of OS X is rendering the `UL` with some sort of background property.  Its just a shot in the dark but maybe try `background: transparent;` on the `UL`.  Or, if it will serve the same purpose, try moving the background color and border-radius to the `UL`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, on FF20, but it appeared to only be me having accidently zoomed in on the page. Resetting the zoom to 0 removed the line.

Comment: Considering that the entire question is specific to an issue in Safari and not Firefox, I'm not entirely sure this answer adds any value to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using even numbers instead of odd numbers will work: Safari 6.0.5 on ML

In my case I tested the following:

```
border-radius: 4px; /* HAPPY */
border-radius: 5px; /* SAD */
border-radius: 6px; /* HAPPY */
```

This appears to be a browser bug.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me (also Safari 6.0.5 on ML). Normally it's fine with any `border-radius`, but when the element also has a `transition` I found it having this problem with the aliasing like effect. So I changed my `border-radius` from `3px` to `4px` and it works as expected!

Answer (score -4):

Try the following to adjust the border radius:

```
border-top-right-radius:10px;
-webkit-top-right-border-radius:10px;
border-top-left-radius:10px;
-webkit-top-left-border-radius:10px;
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question.